# Is it recreate in variable memory for each scroll event?

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, addeventlistener, sticky

I have an element with the name **".offer"** class right above the footer inside the page. When I approach this element in the scroll movement, I want the sticky header to close.

I wrote a function in scroll event for this but I am curious about something.

When I create a function like the example below, are the variables in the function re-created in memory for each scroll move? Or what's the truth for performance in a simple page scroll event?

```
const stickyNearOfferClose = () => {

let scrollPos; 
let header = document.querySelector("header");
const documentOffset = document.querySelector(".offer").offsetTop;

  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY);
  scrollPos = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPos >= documentOffset) {
      header.classList.add("hide");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("hide");
    }
};


window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  stickyNearOfferClose();
});
```

In addition to the above question

When I want to use the above function for one or more scroll actions,

Should we use it define variables  inside a function or within an object for both in terms of performance and usability?

I shared two different examples below. Which one do you think should be?

```
const Obj = {
  scrollPos : null,
  elHeader: document.querySelector("header"),
  documentOffset: document.querySelector(".offer").offsetTop,
  // otherfunction (){},
  stickyNearOfferClose() {
    Obj.elHeader.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY);

    if (Obj.scrollPos >= Obj.documentOffset) {
      Obj.elHeader.classList.add("hide");
    } else {
      Obj.elHeader.classList.remove("hide");
    }
  },
  // init(){}
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  Obj.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  requestAnimationFrame(Obj.stickyNearOfferClose);
});


// OR


const Obj = {
  // variables
  stickyNearOfferClose() {
    let scrollPos;
    const elHeader = document.querySelector("header");
    const elOffer = document.querySelector(".offer");
    const documentOffset = elOffer.offsetTop;

      let stickyClose = () => {
        elHeader.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY);
          if (scrollPos >= documentOffset) {
            elHeader.classList.add("hide");
          } else {
            elHeader.classList.remove("hide");
          }
      };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      scrollPos = window.scrollY;
      requestAnimationFrame(stickyClose);
    });
  },
  spyScrolling() {
    let scrollPos;
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".hero");

    let scrollActiveUrl = () => {
      for (let s in sections) {
        if (
          sections.hasOwnProperty(s) &&
          sections[s].offsetTop <= scrollPos + 150
        ) {
          const id = sections[s].id;
          document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
          document.querySelector(`a[href*=${id}]`).classList.add("active");
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
      requestAnimationFrame(scrollActiveUrl);
    });
  }
  init(){
    this.stickyNearOfferClose();
    this.spyScrolling()
  }
};
```

Comment: Listening to `scroll` event is not a good approach. Look at [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the variables in the function will be recreated on every scroll events. But in your case, you can put some variables outside of the function to save a bit.

As per MDN, you shouldn't call expensive DOM manipulations directly in the function. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using `requestAnimationFrame()`, `setTimeout()`, or a `CustomEvent`. You can learn more at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

**Following is the improved example of your code:**

```
let scrollPos;
const elHeader = document.querySelector("header");
const elOffer = document.querySelector(".offer");
// Note: I'm assuming that `documentOffset` don't need to be updated on every scroll events.
//       Update it as `scrollPos` if it need to be updated on every scroll events.
const documentOffset = elOffter.offsetTop;;

const stickyNearOfferClose = () => {
  
  // Note: Please move the following line in the scroll event 
  //       if it's also needed to be called on every scroll events.
  elHeader.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY);

  if (scrollPos >= documentOffset) {
    elHeader.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    elHeader.classList.remove("hide");
  }
};


window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  requestAnimationFrame(stickyNearOfferClose);
});
```